How do I undo notifications sent using Firebase?
I have a notification system that sends RSS feeds to subscribers.
An error occurred in one of my codes and it sent too many notifications at the same time.
Is there a way to undo this from console, so that I prevent notifications from reaching users?

No.  Once a message is sent, there is no way to cancel delivery within the FCM service.
